# QGIS Atlas with two dynamic maps (only one controlled by Atlas)

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have some different routes with different POIs, and I want to show these POIs in a detailed map and also the position of the POIs in the route, showing all the routes.

[image]

I have two layers, one layer with the routes (LineString), with attribute `Id_Route`, and another layer with POIs (Points) with attributes `Id_Route`, `Id_POI` and `POI_Description`.

I create a Map controlled by Atlas, and Atlas is controlled by Id_POI, that shows a detailed map of POI. I also create a map that shows all the route, and a star where the POI is in the route. This map is not controlled by Atlas because if I control by Atlas, the extent change when the POI change, and I always want the same zoom. If I fixed then all works fine because the complete route is showed. My problem is when I generate an atlas with all points, when the POI is from another route, the zoom/view does not change to the new route.

[image: How I Control/Configure Map of POI]

[image: How I Control/Configure Map of Route]

Any ideas?

Result with @Babel solution:

[image: Result with @Babel solution]

Result with control with atlas:

[image]

Result with buffered points:

[image: Result with buffered points]

Comment: You had a tag for PyQGIS but presented no code attempt to illustrate what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck so I removed it.

Comment: I generate JPG's with atlas in stand alone apllication (PyQgis). It's true that in this question perhaps is not important PyQgis. I marked PyQgis because perhaps solution is a PyQgis code... It's ok, thank you.

Comment: can you use a style rule (based on atlas feature id) in the overview map?

Comment: @Ian Turton, I tried also with overview map, but overview show a part of map that shows POI, not of the route.

Comment: You will have to describe exactly which steps you took and what your current setup looks like in detail.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I put two images to show my configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution: control extent of map position (Route) by Expression String Builder.

[image]

For example for determining `x_min` extent I use this code:

```
x_min(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route'))))))
```

First I get **`value`** of Id_Route of current POI that is showing in atlas.

```
Id_Route = attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route')
```

After that I search a `feature` (Route) in Routes that have this Id_Route.

```
Feature = get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',Id_Route)
```

After, I get `geometry` of this feature (Route).

```
Geometry = geometry(Feature)
```

Finally I get de `x_min` of the Geometry (Route).

```
x_min(Geometry)
```

For `x_max,y_min and y_max`, I do the same, but from Geometry(Route) I extract x_max,y_min and y_max

Whith this code I have a map just with route extension, but I want some pad arround the route (15%).

I find this page where is very well explained how to do:

https://techoverflow.net/2021/04/26/how-to-make-bounding-box-larger-by-a-percentage-in-python/

```
xmin -= 0.15 * (xmax - xmin)
xmax += 0.15 * (xmax - xmin)
ymin -= 0.15 * (ymax - ymin)
ymax += 0.15 * (ymax - ymin)
```

For all the position the code is for 15% of margin:

```
x_min(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route'))))-( 0.15 * (x_max(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route')))) - x_min(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route'))))))

y_min(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route')))) - (0.15 * (y_max(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route')))) - y_min(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route'))))))

x_max(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route')))) + (0.15 * (x_max(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route')))) - x_min(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route'))))))

y_max(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route')))) + (0.15 * (y_max(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route')))) - y_min(geometry( get_feature( 'Routes','Id_Route',attribute(@atlas_feature,'Id_Route'))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your map to the layout, set Atlas (what you already did)
2. Add **another** map to the layout, create an Overview and set `Map frame` to follow the first map (see screenshot). You can set a fixed value for this overview map - it is not affected by atlas.

   *[3. Optional: define different styles with rule based syling in the QGIS main window a) for the current atlas feature with the filter expression  `@atlas_featureid =$id` (red star on the screenshot) b) all other features with the filter expression  `@atlas_featureid <> $id` (white dots).]*

The overview map will show the whole extent of the layer. If you want to have it zoomed in a bit to the current atlas feature, on the overlay map, click also `Controlled by atlas` and set a `Margin around feature` - it can be quite large, e.g. 2000%. *Be aware*: if using a point layer as coverage layer for the atlas, you won't be able to choose this option. Use a polygon layer, representing the points, as coverage layer instead. Create a (small) buffer around the points and use this as coverage layer for the atlas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I try what you say, but I have one problem. The 2nd Map (Route Map), show all extens of the feature in the layer, so the extens is very big, and the route see small. Do you know if I can control zoom?

Comment: I add a screen capture with resault in my question.

Comment: I don't know why I can't select Margin around feature. I add print screen. Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: See 2nd update to my answer.

Comment: I do what you say and the problem now, is the limit arround is 9.999%, and is not enough. Thank you again for your help!!!!!

Comment: Increase the value. Make 20%, 50%, 100% or whatever value is good for you.

Comment: Yes I do it, but the limit is 9999%. You can't increase more, and the route is not hole visible, I put a print screen in my question.